# Multiple URL parameters?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver and would like to add multiple parameters to my my link. Right now I have one parameter which works fine, but I would like to add multiple parameters to the same link, how do I do that?

The code to the link is as follows:

```
<a href="Patient.php?Patient=<?php echo
$row_Patienter['Patient']; ?>">Visa</a>
```

This does links to another page's Recordset.

My question is: 
How do I add multiple parameters to the same link? How would it look like?

Comment: This is not specific to Dreamweaver or any other IDE for that matter. Separate each additional variable with an ampersand `&`

Comment: The format is `url?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2`

Comment: Also, don't forget to [**urlencode**](http://www.php.net/urlencode) your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate parameters by adding a & at the end of each parameter.
Something like:

```
http://www.domain.com?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2
```

But in your case I would recommend to do it like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='patien.php?parameter1=".$value1."&parameter2=".$value2."'>Link</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add extra parameters by starting with `?` and adding `&` each time you start a new parameter. Remember in HTML to use `&amp;`

```
<a href="Patient.php?Patient=<?php echo $row_Patienter['Patient']; ?>&amp;value2=<?php echo $value2?>">Visa</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="bar.php?foo=<php echo $foo; ?>&bar=<?php echo $bar; ?>">
```

or whatever the values are. Better use echo, not sure what you wrote works